# How to add next arrows to javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript slideshow. I'd like to add arrows that will go to the next or previous slides accordingly, but I'm not sure how to go about it. My only idea is to create a next and previous arrow for each slide and link them to the appropriate slides, but I can't help but think there's a more efficient way than creating 6 arrows.

```
var counter = 0;
var divs = jQuery('#slider_1, #slider_2, #slider_3');

function showDiv() {
    divs.fadeOut('slow').delay(500).filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }).fadeIn('slow');
    counter++;
};

showDiv();  

setInterval(function () {
    showDiv();
}, 8 * 1000);
```

Comment: There's a bit more to this than just "adding arrows". You'd have to add a backwards and forwards arrow in your HTML that remain in front of the slider. Then, wire them up to `nextSlide` and `prevSlide` functions (that you currently don't have).

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle.  My first attempt would be you need to define prevArrow and nextArrow buttons within showDiv(), and then take advantage of the counter++ and counter-- within click functions.

Comment: I can't get it working on jfiddle, though it works fine on the website. Could I put an event listener inside of showDiv and increment/decrement the count?